# Android R file update at runtime

Tags: android

Is it possible to examine the R file and update its contents via reflection in an Android application. I was looking to change the value various constants defined in the R file ? Is it possible ? Would it make sense ?

Comment: What is the purpose of change the values in R.java runtimely?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do by changing the R file, you can do it programmatically in your code and the change will automatically reflect on OR file. You should never change anything in R file it's an auto generated file which keeps Static code. IF you change anything forcefully even though while building the apk it will clean your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and, in my opinion, it wouldn't make sense.

The values in the `R` class change when you build your application and you can never guarantee that they will be the same. The integer values are not meant to be used directly, only they static constants should be used in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible and it would not make sense.

`R` is a set of static fields. There is nothing you can do to change that.
Everything is baked into it on compile time.